# To find a limit involving integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-integration

How to find the following limit : $\lim _{x \to \infty} \dfrac 1 x \int_0^x \dfrac {dt}{1+x^2 \cos^2 t}$ ? I am not even sure whether the limit exists or not .  I tried applying L'Hospital , but then in the numerator we have differentiation under integration, and the derivative comes out to be lot messier than the original integral. Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$F(x)=\frac {1}{x} \int_0^x \dfrac {dt}{1+x^2 \cos^2 t}$$
Then for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, since $\cos^2(t)$ is $\pi$-periodic,
\begin{align*}
F(n\pi)
&=
\frac {1}{n\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \dfrac {dt}{1+(n\pi)^2 \cos^2 t}\\
&=\frac {1}{n\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac {dt}{1+(n\pi)^2 \cos^2 t}
=\frac {1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac {dt}{1+(n\pi)^2 \cos^2 t}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2\pi^2}}.
\end{align*}
which goes to zero as $n\to +\infty$.

Note that if $0<n\pi\leq x< (n+1)\pi$ then
$$0\leq F(x)\leq \frac {1}{n\pi} \int_0^{(n+1)\pi} \dfrac {dt}{1+(n\pi)^2 \cos^2 t}=F(n\pi)+\frac {1}{n\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac {dt}{1+(n\pi)^2 \cos^2 t}.$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @RobertZ :  Ok , but then you are evaluating the limit on the particular sequence $x_n = n\pi \to \infty $ ... the required limit would be equal to the limit evaluated on this sequence if we already knew the limit exists ... how do you ensure that the limit exists ?

Comment: @misao See my edited answer again.

Comment: @Robert Z : $\int \dfrac {dt }{1+x^2\cos^2 t}= \dfrac {arctan (\dfrac{\tan t}{\sqrt{x^2+1}})}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ + constant ... right  ( Found from Wolfram Alpha ) ? Then shouldn't your $F(n\pi)$ be $0$ ?

Comment: @Robert Z : So $F(x)$ is an increasing function ?

Comment: @misao No, I am not saying that $F$ is increasing (see $(n+1)\pi$ in the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: @Robert Z : ah so only $xF(x)$ is increasing .. that much you are assuming .. but your evaluation of the integral in $F(n\pi)$ is definitely wrong ..

Comment: @misao Let $F(x,y,z)=\frac {1}{x} \int_0^y \dfrac {dt}{1+z^2 \cos^2 t}$ it is clear that since the integrand is positive $F$ is decreasing in $x$ and $z$ and increasing in $y$. Do you agree?

Comment: @Robert Z : you seem to forget that here $x=y=z$ so they are not independent variable ..

Comment: @misao $F(x)>0$ for $x>0$. You are integrating a positive function!  How can it be zero?

Comment: @Robert Z : ah uh , that's true .. a positive continuous function, that makes sense ... then could you please take a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+dt%2F1%2Ba%5E2cos%5E2+t .. and could you tell me how you are evaluating the integral ?

Comment: @misao Let $H(x,y,z)=\frac {1}{x} \int_0^y \dfrac {dt}{1+z^2 \cos^2 t}$ it is clear that since the integrand is positive $H$ is decreasing in $x$ and $z$ and increasing in $y$. Now for $0<n\pi\leq x< (n+1)\pi$,
$$F(x)=H(x,x,x)\leq H(n\pi,x,x)\leq H(n\pi,x,n\pi)\leq H(n\pi,(n+1)\pi,n\pi).$$

Comment: @misao : Wolfram is correct. But the that formula has a problem at $\pi/2$ (which is inside the interval). By symmetry you can take 2 times the integral along $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @Robert Z : Thanks , I got it all

Comment: @misao Well done!

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall x > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}\ s.t. \ x \in ]2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi]$$

$$ 0 \leq \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+x^2\cos^2(t)}  \leq \frac{1}{2n\pi}\int_0^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2\cos^2(t)}$$
$$ \leq \frac{1}{2n\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^{2(k+1)\pi}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2\cos^2(t)}$$
$$ \leq \frac{1}{2n\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2\cos^2(t)}$$
$$ \leq \frac{1}{2n\pi}\sum_{k=0}^n4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2\cos^2(t)}$$
$$ \leq \frac{2(n+1)}{n\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2\cos^2(t)}$$
$$ \leq \frac{2(n+1)}{n\pi}\int_0^{1}\frac{dt}{1+(2n\pi)^2t^2}$$
$$ \leq \frac{2(n+1)}{n\pi}\frac{\pi}{4n\pi} \to 0$$