Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{1+t^2\sin^{2}(t)}dt$
How to find this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{1+t^2\sin^{2}(t)}dt$$
I guess the $\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{t}{1+t^2\sin^{2}(t)}dt$ grows as fast as the $x$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Maybe this helps - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2354771/1157207

Do you know about the Leibnitz integral rule?

@RDK The problem was specific enough, and no more detail was needed to identify adequate answers. What was missing is rather some more thoughts and efforts.

@MathGuy I do, but I can't see how it would help.

This is to provide a rigorous proof that the desired limit is equal 1.
$$S(s)=\int_0^x\frac{tdt}{1+t^2\sin^2t}\overset{t=\pi s}{=}\pi^2\int_0^\frac x\pi\frac{sds}{1+\pi^2s^2\sin^2(\pi s)}$$
Without loss of generality we can consider $\frac x\pi=n$ - integer (in general case we can consider $\displaystyle \int_0^{[\frac x\pi]}$, taking the integer part, and then show that the integral on the interval $\Big[[\frac x\pi]; \frac x\pi\Big]$ is $o(x)$).
Hence, denoting $n=\frac x\pi$ and using the periodicity of $\sin^2(\pi s)$
$$S(s)=\pi^2\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{s+k}{1+\pi^2(s+k)^2\sin^2(\pi s)}\right)ds$$
All the terms are positive; therefore
$$\frac{k}{1+\pi^2(1+k)^2\sin^2(\pi s)}<\frac{s+k}{1+\pi^2(s+k)^2\sin^2(\pi s)}<\frac{1+k}{1+\pi^2k^2\sin^2(\pi s)}$$
Using
$$\pi^2\int_0^1\frac {ds}{1+a^2\sin^2(\pi s)}=2\pi\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{dt}{1+a^2\sin^2t}\overset{s=\tan t}{=}2\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{1+(1+a^2)s^2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}$$
we get the estimation of our sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\pi^2k}{\sqrt{\pi^2(k+1)^2+1}}<S<\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\pi^2(k+1)}{\sqrt{\pi^2k^2+1}}$$
Multiplying the expression by $\frac1x=\frac1{\pi n}$ and taking the limit $n\to \infty$, we get 1

Thank you, I successfully solved this problem two days ago. My idea is similar to yours, and I also convert the integral into a series, but I take $\pi$ as the interval. Finally, I used the Squeeze Theorem, and the answer is also 1.

To evaluate the limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1 + t^2 \sin^2(t)} \, dt,
$$
we can analyze the behavior of the integrand $\frac{t}{1 + t^2 \sin^2(t)}$ as $t$ becomes large.
For large $t$, the term $t^2 \sin^2(t)$ oscillates between $0$ and $t^2$. The behavior of the integrand depends on the value of $\sin(t)$:

Away from multiples of $\pi$: When $t$ is not near a multiple of $\pi$, $\sin^2(t)$ is bounded away from zero. In this case, the integrand behaves roughly like $\frac{t}{t^2} = \frac{1}{t}$, which contributes a logarithmic term upon integration.

Near multiples of $\pi$: When $t$ is near $n\pi$ for some integer $n$, $\sin(t)$ is small, and the integrand approximates to $\frac{t}{1} \approx n\pi$. The integral in these regions contributes a finite amount proportional to $\pi$ for each such neighborhood.


Each peak contributes approximately $\pi$ to the integral. Since there are roughly $\frac{x}{\pi}$ such peaks up to $x$, the total contribution from these peaks is approximately:
$$
\frac{x}{\pi} \times \pi = x.
$$
The integral away from the peaks behaves like $\int \frac{1}{t} \, dt$, which grows logarithmically as $\log(x)$. However, this is negligible compared to the linear growth from the peaks.
Thus, the integral behaves asymptotically as:
$$
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{t}{1 + t^2 \sin^2(t)} \, dt \approx x + \log(x).
$$
Dividing by $x$ and taking the limit as $x \to \infty$:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \left( x + \log(x) \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{\log(x)}{x}\right) = 1.
$$
Thus, the final answer is: $1$.

I guess your evaluation is correct (+1). Regarding numeric check - please, have a look at my comment to the other post )

Thanks, @Svyatoslav! This was my initial analytical solution, but then I became suspicious about that, when I went to confirm the answer were 1, by using a numerical approach. It took me some time to decide what the correct numeric solution is.

Thank you,your evaluation is correct.

Comment
Numerically, it seems the limit is zero.  Or, at worst, something below $0.1$.
$$
\frac1x\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{1+t^2\sin^{2}(t)}dt
$$


Are you really sure, @GEdgar, about that? Given the oscillatory nature of $\sin$, the numeric algorithm needs to consider a lot of points. The default number of points may not be enough. I have just used python to calculate the limit numerically, by considering sub-intervals of $\pi$ width (one integral by sub-interval), and the result is 1!

NAG method d01akc is supposed to be applicable to oscillatory integrals.

I guess it is the same algorithm scipy's quad uses: scipy.quad. However, by using the same algorithm and integrate by sub-intervals of $\pi$, we get 1 as result: quad(integrand, current, upper, limit=1000).

It seems that numerically the limit 1 is correct. WA (free option) shows the miracles when evaluating the integral even for comparatively small $x$. For example, for $x=100$ it provides two different answers - depending on how we write $\frac1x: ,\frac 1{100}$ or 0.01 :) - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F100%5Cint_0%5E%7B100%7Dt%2F%28%281%2Bt%5E2%5Csin%5E%7B2%7D%28t%29%29%29dt and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.01%5Cint_0%5E%7B100%7Dt%2F%28%281%2Bt%5E2%5Csin%5E%7B2%7D%28t%29%29%29dt The issue is in methodics of numeric evaluation
